# visual studio 2012 datagrid syntax

Tags: c#

I'm busy developing a Import Program which import's excel files into a datagrid and then inserting those data fields from the datagrid to a SQL database.

I'm not struggling with inserting the data via text boxes and so forth.It seems in VS2012 the syntax has changed for selecting a certain row or even column from c# into sql. 
The syntax I found does not work:

```
datagridView1.Rows[0].ToString().
```

Here Follows my Code:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
Conn.ConnectionString = (Excel.DBCon);

// Open the Database Connection
Conn.Open();

// Command String
string Insert_Cmd = @"insert into tblCustomer(CustomerID,CustomerName) Values
    ('" + Guid.NewGuid() + "','" +dtGrid.SelectedCells[0].ToString() + "')";

// Initialize the Command Query and Connection
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Insert_Cmd, Conn);

// Execute the Command
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("One Record Inserted");
```

This code works but the result I get back from the db is the following: `System.Data.DataRowView` there has to be a correct syntax to select the value/values from that column/columns or cells. Please feel free to share

Comment: you need sth in the sense of dtGrid.SelectedCells[0].[j].ToString()

Comment: Do you mean C# syntax instead of Visual Studio syntax? Syntax describes the layout of a language, which Visual Studio is not.